# How to seperate strings from json object

Tags: c#, json

When I use below code in my C#

```
var resultset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(objInputData.ServiceInputData);
```

I get the resultset as below

```js
{
  "Inputdata": [
    {
      "EmpId": "13390",
      "ContractId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get `EmpId` and `ContractId` into a variables in C#?

Below is my code where I store the `EmpId` into a variable. But it seems to be wrong.

```
var EmpId = resultset.EmpId;
var ContractId = resultset.ContractId;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is always helpful is you explain what is not working. Saying it is "wrong" doesn't really help people diagnose your problem.

You are probably getting a compiler error telling you something to the effect of "EmpId is not a property of object". That's because the version of `DeserializeObject` that you're calling returns an `object` and `object` doesn't have an `EmpId` property.

The simplest solution is to deserialize into strongly-typed classes (generated using http://json2csharp.com):

```
public class Inputdata
{
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Inputdata> Inputdata { get; set; }
}
```

Then use:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(objInputData.ServiceInputData);
```

The `Inputdata` is actually a list so you may potentially get multiples.

```
foreach(var inputData in result.Inputdata)
{
    // inputData.EmpId
    // inputData.ContractId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your json above inputData is an ARRAY so it it would be

```
var EmpId = resultset.Inputdata[0].EmpId; 
var ContractId = resultset.Inputdata[0].ContractId;
```

Comment: That still won't work. He's using the overload of `DeserializeObject` that returns an `object` so he'll still get a compilation error that `Inputdata` isn't a property of `object`.